# Changing the color of word "Proof"

Tags: amsthm

I'm using `\begin{proof}... \end{proof}` of `amsthm` package for demonstrations environment. How I can change only the color of word "Proof"? Thank you.

R.S.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest an indirect method. For some time I've endorsed replacing the hardwired `\itshape` with a generic command that can be modified by the user. Alas, it has never been done.

But we can patch `\proof` and do it ourselves.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch \proof

\newcommand{\proofnameformat}{\itshape}% the default for amsthm
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\proofnameformat}{}{}

\colorlet{proofcolor}{red!75!blue}
\renewcommand{\proofnameformat}{\itshape\color{proofcolor}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `twocolumn` option is just to make a smaller picture.

I suggest keeping the default value of `\proofnameformat` for the record, so you start from the same setup as the standard `amsthm`.

A more flexible version might be

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xpatch}% to patch \proof

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\proofnameformat}[1]{\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}}% the default \xpatchcmd{\proof}
  {\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}}
  {\proofnameformat{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
for amsthm

\colorlet{proofcolor}{red!75!blue}
\renewcommand{\proofnameformat}[1]{\fbox{\itshape\color{proofcolor}#1\/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Here `#1` in the definition of `\proofnameformat` will be replaced by `\proofname`. The result with the given value for `\proofnameformat` would be

[image]

For your application you'd do

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\proofnameformat}{\itshape\color{proofcolor}#1\@addpunct{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

The default "proof name" is defined as `\proofname` in `amsthm`.
So you can just `\renewcommand*` it.

Example below gives you the word "Proof" in red.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\proofname}{\color{red}Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Test
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. However, one may want to replace `\color{red}Proof` with either `{\color{red}Proof}` or `\textcolor{red}{Proof}` if one doesn't want the period (aka "full stop") after the string "Proof" to be colored red as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative.....redefing with `\newenvironment{prof}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{prof}
{\begin{proof}[\itshape\textcolor{red}{Proof.}]}
{\end{proof}} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{prof}
        Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.
    \end{prof}
\end{document}
```